# How to fetch the image or PDF from a server and save it in local machine?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Fetching Pdf/Images:

```
Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Demo.pdf");
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("www.dfdg.com\\Documents\\Documents\\Docnoc1894.pdf"));
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a much different approach than what you are currently trying to do but, if you want to locally save a file from the web, the following code may help. Sorry if I did not understand nor answered your question.

```
string theFileToDownload = "http://www.dfdg.com/Documents/Documents/Docnoc1894.pdf";
string theSaveToPath = "c:\\temp\\DownloadedFile\\Docnoc1894.pdf";
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
wc.DownloadFile(theFileToDownload, theSaveToPath);
wc.Dispose();
```

Comment: "An exception occurred during a WebClient request its some error is there its not working

Comment: As-is, the code would indeed throw an error. currently the string "theFileToDownload" is a string that does not resolve to anything. So first thing is to replace that link with a valid one. Then you'll want to make sure the string "theSaveToPath" is a valid path as well. The folder structure into which you'll save the file must exist before you download the file to the location.

Answer (score 0):

This code is very close. It's important to fetch the document from a folder that is accesible in runtime (AppData works fine in my case).

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=report.pdf");
Response.WriteFile(Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data"), "report.pdf"));
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

Comment: its locally download file method i am trying this method but its not working

Comment: It would be helpful for me to know what error did you get